# Deja Dup Permission Denied after creating initial directory

Tags: permissions, backup, deja-dup, google-drive

I am running `deja-dup` v40.6 (installed with `snap`) on Ubuntu 18.04, using Google as the storage backend.  When I run a backup, a directory gets successfully created in my Google Drive with the correct name -- but then failes after transferring no files.  The output (with debug enabled) follows.

I had been running backups prior to this and deleted them.  Is there another file somewhere?  Or leftover credentials laying around?  The fact that it creates the directory means the authorization seems to be working.

```
DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . Main action: remove-all-but-n-full

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Acquiring lockfile b'/home/[elided]/snap/deja-dup/common/.cache/deja-dup/3c3719d408f2f097e930c1b5405eaa33/lockfile'

DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . ================================================================================

DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . duplicity 0.8.11

DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . Args: /snap/deja-dup/297/bin/duplicity remove-all-but-n-full 1 --force gio+google-drive://[elided]/Workstation%20Backups --no-encryption --verbosity=9 --archive-dir=/home/[elided]/snap/deja-dup/common/.cache/deja-dup --tempdir=/tmp --log-fd=29

DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . Linux [elided] 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64

DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . /snap/core18/current/usr/bin/python3 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
DUPLICITY: . [GCC 8.3.0]

DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . ================================================================================

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Backtrace of previous error: Traceback (innermost last):
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/297/lib/python3.6/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 376, in inner_retry
DUPLICITY: .     return fn(self, *args)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/297/lib/python3.6/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 596, in list
DUPLICITY: .     return [tobytes(x) for x in self.backend._list()]
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/297/lib/python3.6/site-packages/duplicity/backends/giobackend.py", line 161, in _list
DUPLICITY: .     None)
DUPLICITY: .  gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-io-error-quark: Permission denied (14)
```